# I want to view it in datagrid which the input will be added each time the user clicks the button

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to view it in datagrid which the input will be added each time the user clicks the button..How would I make it to do that..Now it can be saved to database...But I want it to view in the interface itself in datagrid order which each time the user click on add data,it would save into database together it displays in the datagrid format in front-end..TQ

```
  protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["Time"].ToString() == ViewState["Time"].ToString())
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=RGUNASEL-   DESK\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=eLogbook;User ID=sa;Password=1234");
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("eform2", connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lot_num", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = TextBox8.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@location", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = TextBox9.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@total_in", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox10.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@first_test", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = TextBox11.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@second_test", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox12.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@third_test", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = TextBox13.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@total_out", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = TextBox14.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lot_status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = TextBox17.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@remark", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = TextBox16.Text;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("Submitted!");
            TextBox8.Text = null;
            TextBox9.Text = null;
            TextBox10.Text = null;
            TextBox11.Text = null;
            TextBox12.Text = null;
            TextBox13.Text = null;
            TextBox14.Text = null;
            TextBox17.Text = null;
            TextBox16.Text = null;


            Session["Time"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            // Code for page refresh....
            TextBox8.Text = null;
            TextBox9.Text = null;
            TextBox10.Text = null;
            TextBox11.Text = null;
            TextBox12.Text = null;
            TextBox13.Text = null;
            TextBox14.Text = null;
            TextBox17.Text = null;
            TextBox16.Text = null;
            Response.Write("Page Refreshed!");
        }

    }
```

Comment: instead of setting all the individual TextBoxes.Text = to null why not use a `foreach loop and check foreach (Control in controls){} then set each TextBox.Text = string.Empty;` eliminates having to hard code the values what if you had 100 TextBoxes..? why write the same code 100 times when you can write 4-6 lines of code to handle all 100 TextBoxes just some suggestions to cleanup the code outside of your original issue also think about changing cmd.Parameters.Add() Method to use cmd.Parameters.AddWithValues()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey no need of checking time and all just Rebind the gridview after each data/row adding.

like

```
//Code to bind gridview
Dataset dst=yourFunctionToGetRequiredTableRows();
yourGridView.DataSource=dst;
yourGridView.Databind();
```

ie

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=RGUNASEL-   DESK\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=eLogbook;User ID=sa;Password=1234");
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("eform2", connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lot_num", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = TextBox8.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@location", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = TextBox9.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@total_in", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox10.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@first_test", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = TextBox11.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@second_test", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox12.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@third_test", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = TextBox13.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@total_out", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = TextBox14.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lot_status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = TextBox17.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@remark", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = TextBox16.Text;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //Response.Write("Submitted!");

        //Code to bind gridview
        Dataset dst=yourFunctionToGetRequiredTableRows();
        yourGridView.DataSource=dst;
        yourGridView.Databind();

    }
```

EDIT:

```
public Dataset yourFunctionToGetRequiredTableRows()
{
 Dataset dst=new Dataset();
 //"your SQL SELECT statement here".
 return dst;
}
```

Comment: I have tried using your code man..but it is not working...I get this error "Error 1 The name 'yourFunctionToGetRequiredTableRows' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\rgunasel\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\elogbook_form\elogbook_form\WebForm1.aspx.cs".Why I am getting this kind of error..Pls help

Comment: 'yourFunctionToGetRequiredTableRows()' this is the function name which you have to define as per your req.

Comment: I have to define it in the client side is it?